# Displaying data from dictionary using flask, pythonanywhere

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, pythonanywhere

I am trying to display some simple 3 day weather forecast data using pythonanywhere flask app. Here is my code so far:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import requests
from collections import defaultdict


app = Flask(__name__)

r = requests.get("http://api.wunderground.com/api/mykey/forecast/q/SouthAFrica/Stellenbosch.json")
data = r.json()
weather_data = defaultdict(list)

counter = 0
for day in data['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday']:
    date= day['date']['weekday'] + ":"
    cond=  "Conditions: ", day['conditions']
    temp= "High: ", day['high']['celsius'] + "C", "Low: ", day['low']['celsius'] + "C"


    counter = counter + 1

    weather_data[counter].append(date)
    weather_data[counter].append(cond)
    weather_data[counter].append(temp)

return weather_data

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html', weather_data=weather_data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

and here is the simple 'home.html':

```
<table>
{% for key,value in weather_data.items() %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{value[1]}}</td>
        <td>{{value[2]}}</td>
        <td>{{value[3]}}</td>
        <td>{{value[4]}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

I can't seem to get this to work. I suspect it is something to do with the format of the data? Should it rather be a separate file that is imported?

Comment: You don't say what the problem is, but I suspect it has something to do with the dangling return in the middle of nowhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the python logic within your view function, like this:

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    r = requests.get("http://api.wunderground.com/api/key/forecast/q/SouthAfrica/Stellenbosch.json")
    data = r.json()
    weather_data = defaultdict(list)

    counter = 0
    for day in data['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday']:
        date = day['date']['weekday'] + ":"
        cond = "Conditions: ", day['conditions']
        temp = "High: ", day['high']['celsius'] + "C", "Low: ", day['low']['celsius'] + "C"

        counter += 1

        weather_data[counter].append(date)
        weather_data[counter].append(cond)
        weather_data[counter].append(temp)

    return render_template('home.html', weather_data=weather_data)
```

By looking at the API data I think your `{{ value[1] }}` is still a tuple so you might need something like `{{ value[1][0] }}, {{ value[1][1] }}` in your template to render this data.

Add print statements to your python to debug how to parse the data structure.